# When do I need to use an OpenGL function loader?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I'm a bit confused about when exactly I need to use an OpenGL function loader like GLEW. In general, it seems like you first obtain a window and valid OpenGL context and then attempt to load functions.

- Sometimes these functions are referred to as extensions, sometimes they are called core functions as well. It seems like what's loaded and classified as 'core' and 'extension' is platform dependent. Are the functions that are loaded in addition to some base set?
- Do you need to load functions in the same way on OpenGL ES platforms as well? Taking a quick look at GLEW, I don't see any explicit support for Open GL ES. Other GL function loader libs do explicitly mention support specifically for ES however (like https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad)

Comment: Not only does GLEW not support OpenGL ES, it doesn't really support core contexts either, since it botches extension detection--`glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` does not work in core, you need `glGetStringi(GL_EXTENSIONS, n)`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: It supports core contexts, but in a really roundabout way. Instead of using `glGetStringi(...)`, you set `glewExperimental` and then instead of parsing the extension string, it will blindly try to load every function an extension defines. If 100% of the functions defined by an extension come back with a non-NULL function pointer w/ `glewExperimental`, then GLEW considers that extension implemented. That behavior was originally designed to load extensions that a driver implemented but did not advertise, but later became the mechanism used to workaround core profile shenanigans.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: I've used that before, but that workaround has some pretty severe flaws: there are a lot of extensions out there with no entry points, or entry points that have the same names as entry points for other extensions, or entry points which exist on your system but don't work, or which define behavior not encapsulated by entry points.  Sorry, but that's just broken!  I've had problems with programs crashing because they set `glewExperimental`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I think you may have been using GLEW incorrectly if your program crashed after setting `glewExperimental`. You must have been assuming that a non-NULL function pointer associated with one extension implied something about the existence of another. GLEW's just there to load all of the function pointers when `glewExperimental` is set, nothing else. You cannot really rely on `glewIsSupported (...)` to give you accurate information anymore, but you can trivially parse `glGetStringi (...)` yourself.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Right... I can always do it myself, but then why wouldn't I just switch to a GL loader that's not quite so broken?  It's GLEW's job to report which extensions are available, and this is just plain broken.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OpenGL functions (core or extension) must be loaded at runtime, dynamically, whenever the function in question is not part of the platforms original OpenGL ABI (application **binary** interface).

- For Windows the ABI covers is OpenGL-1.1
- For Linux the ABI covers OpenGL-1.2 (there's no official OpenGL ABI for other *nixes, but they usually require OpenGL-1.2 as well)
- For MacOS X the OpenGL version available and with it the ABI is defined by the OS version.

This leads to the following rules:

- In Windows you're going to need a function loader for pretty much everything, except single textured, shaderless, fixed function drawing; it may be possible to load further functionality, but this is not a given.
- In Linux you're going to need a function loader for pretty much everything, except basic multitextured with just the basic texenv modes, shaderless, fixed function drawing; it may be possible to load further functionality, but this is not a given.
- In MacOS X you *don't* need a function loader at all, but the OpenGL features you can use are strictly determined by the OS version, either you have it, or you don't.

The difference between core OpenGL functions and extensions is, that core functions are found in the OpenGL specification, while extensions are functionality that may or may be not available in addition to what the OpenGL version available provides.

Both extensions and newer version core functions are loaded through the same mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you comment on OpenGL ES platforms? If I write an Android or iOS application, do I need to use something like GLEW, or is it more like OS X where the OS strictly determines what's available?

Comment: @Pris: A similar extension mechanism exists for OpenGL-ES. However just like with regular OpenGL the the necessity and exact mechanism being used to load extensions depend on the target environment. In the case iOS the operating system version pins down the minimum available OpenGL-ES version. For Android you have to test what's available.

Comment: I haven't seen any examples of specifically loading function pointers on typical GLES targets like android/ios (which differs from just checking if an implementation has a specific extension)

Comment: On MacOS, the OpenGL features are not strictly determined by the OS version. It also depends on the GPU. For example with the latest MacOS, recent GPUs support 4.1, while older ones only support 3.3. See https://developer.apple.com/opengl/capabilities/.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: I was referring only to the availability of the symbols. The actual OpenGL version supported by the context is a different thing. But OP was asking about function symbols and loading, so I was answering in that context.

Comment: What OpenGL versions are available at build time is not a function of the OS version. That's a function of the platform SDK you build against. The platform SDKs are installed with Xcode.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: However, the platform SDKs target a specific OS version. If you build against 10.10, your software's only going to run on 10.10+ and all of the symbols for 10.10's 4.1 implementation will be defined at link-time (though not necessarily implemented at run-time). I think that's what datenwolf was getting at.

Answer (score 4):

*datenwolf's answer is great, but I wanted to clarify something you said in the first bullet point of your question.*

#### Core and extension status is not platform-dependent or even mutually exclusive.

Core means that some feature was introduced in a certain version of OpenGL. There are core functions, which are things that are guaranteed to exist in version X.Y and there are even core extensions, which are *extensions* that were introduced alongside version X.Y. Core extensions provide the same functions, types, enums, etc. as the core feature only in an extension form that does not require a specific version.

Framebuffer Objects went core in OpenGL 3.0, and are slightly less restrictive than the `EXT` extension ([`GL_EXT_framebuffer_object`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/framebuffer_object.txt)) that predates OpenGL 3.0. However, it is not necessary to have an OpenGL 3.0 implementation to have access to the core version of FBOs - an OpenGL 2.1 implementation might offer the core functionality.

#### In the extension specification for [`GL_ARB_framebuffer_object`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_object.txt), you will find:

> **Issues**
>
> > *(8)* Why don't the new tokens and entry points in this extension have
> >            "ARB" suffixes like other ARB extensions?
> >
> > > **RESOLVED**: Unlike most ARB extensions, this is a strict subset of
> > >               functionality already approved in OpenGL 3.0. This extension
> > >               exists only to support that functionality on older hardware that
> > >               cannot implement a full OpenGL 3.0 driver. Since there are no
> > >               possible behavior changes between the ARB extension and core
> > >               features, source code compatibility is improved by not using
> > >               suffixes on the extension.

That is the first mention of a core extension that I can recall, but it is not the last. Since then many `ARB` extensions have been created that "backport" (if you will) core functionality from a higher version.

#### Here is some sample output gathered by parsing `gl.xml` for another core extension:

```cpp
 >> Command:  void glBufferStorage (GLenum target, GLsizeiptr size, const void *
                                    data, GLbitfield flags)

  * Provided by GL_ARB_buffer_storage (gl|glcore)

  * Core in                   GL_VERSION_4_4    (   gl 4.4)
```

It is core in 4.4 (guaranteed to exist in a 4.4 implementation), but because the extension that provides it is `glcore`, this ***core*** function may be available in older implementations if the core extension is available.

*The simple piece of software I wrote to parse `gl.xml` for this information can be found [here](https://github.com/Andon13/glvs) if you are interested.*

Answer (score 4):

Function loaders are only needed on Windows and Linux. Here's a quick overview of how you build for various OpenGL versions on different platforms.

### Windows

The Windows development tools only contain headers for OpenGL 1.1. The conspiracy theorists would probably claim that Microsoft is not interested in making the use of OpenGL easy because it wants developers to use a proprietary API instead.

For anything beyond 1.1, you need to load the entry points dynamically by calling `wglGetProcAddress()`. Libraries like GLEW provide header files for higher OpenGL versions, and encapsulate the logic for loading the entry points.

### Linux

I haven't done OpenGL programming on Linux. From what I hear, it requires function loading similar to Windows. I'll defer to @datenwolf's answer for the details.

### Mac OS

Mac OS supports two main OpenGL feature sets:

- OpenGL 2.1 with legacy features. This is used by including `<OpenGL/gl.h>`.
- OpenGL 3.x and higher, Core Profile only. Used by including `<OpenGL/gl3.h>`.

In both cases, you don't need any dynamic function loading. The header files contain all the declarations/definitions for the maximum version that can be supported, and the framework you link against (using `-framework OpenGL`) resolves the function names.

The maximum version you can use at build time is determined by the platform SDK you build against. By default, this is he platform SDK that matches the OS of your build machine. But you can change it by using the `-isysroot` build option.

At runtime, the machine has to run at least the OS matching the platform SDK used at build time, and you can only use features up to the version supported by the GPU. You can get an overview of what version is supported on which hardware on:

https://developer.apple.com/opengl/capabilities/
http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823

### Android, NDK

With native code on Android, you choose the OpenGL version while setting up the context and surface. Your code then includes the desired header (like `<GLES2/gl2.h>` or `<GLES3/gl3.h>`) and links against the matching libraries. There is no dynamic function loading needed.

If the target device does not support the version you are trying to use, the context creation will fail. You can have an entry in the manifest that prevents the app from being installed on devices that will not support the required ES version.

### Android, Java

This is very similar to the NDK case. The desired version is specified during setup, e.g. while creating a `GLSurfaceView`.

The `GLES20` class contains the definitions for ES 2.0. `GLES30` derives from `GLES20`, and adds the additional definitions for ES 3.0.

### iOS

Not surprisingly, this is very similar to Mac OS. You include the header file that matches the desired OpenGL ES version (e.g. `<OpenGLES/ES3/gl.h>`), link against the framework, and you're all done.

Also matching Mac OS, the maximum version you can build against is determined by the platform SDK version you choose. Devices you want to run on then have to use at least the OS version that matches this platform SDK version, and support the OpenGL ES version you are using.

One main difference is obviously that you cross compile the app on a Mac. iOS uses a different set of platform SDKs with different headers and frameworks, but the overall process is pretty much the same as building for Mac OS.