# glBlendFuncSeparate not available even in OpenGL 3.0

Tags: c++, opengl

When I compile the code with this function
  `glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA, GL_ONE);`

I get

`error: ‘glBlendFuncSeparate’ was not declared in this scope`

Sure enough when I checked in :

`/usr/include/GL/gl.h`

There is only `glBlendFunc` defined, not the Separate ones.

But according to specification 
https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBlendFuncSeparate.xhtml

This function is available in OpenGL 3.0 and I have OpenGL 3.0

```
 % glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.0.2
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev

sudo apt-get install freeglut3

sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

But it says it is already up to date. I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I wonder why that function is not available?

Comment: Have you tried to use glew?

Comment: That works.. like a charm. Why don't you put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: To make a good answer, I need to explain how modern openGL works, and I'm not confortable in doing that

Comment: The details of how loading modern OpenGL works have been asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873784/when-do-i-need-to-use-an-opengl-function-loader