# How do I tell whether an OpenGL function should be an extension function or not?

Tags: opengl

I have a difficult to debug issue where OpenGL renders (Windows OS) are happening if I load a GL context at 3.1 or less, and not at 3.2 or more (I'm attempting to get to 4.4), with OpenGL throwing an obscure INVALID_OPERATION error on glDrawArraysEXT.

I think the issue could be that one or more functions are being called are an "old" version, using the GL 1.0/1.1 function instead of the equivalent 3.0+ extension method which may be required. For example I replaced glDrawArrays with glDrawArraysEXT which fixed an earlier bug, but maybe there are more functions like this which need a newer version?

So my question is, how do I know if I'm meant to be using a "replacement" extension method for any of my other functions? For example my assumption is glViewport has no extension method (since I tried to load it and it couldn't be found), so using the core version is fine. But how can I check this for all functions I'm calling without using an extension method?

If it helps, here is the list of OpenGL 1.0/1.1 functions I'm currently calling:

- glClear
- glClearColor
- glViewport
- glGetError
- glEnable / glDisable
- glBlendFunc
- glBindTexture
- glGenTextures
- glGetTexImage
- glTexParameteri
- glTexImage2D
- glGetString

Do any of these have an extension method I should be using, and how should I be finding this out myself?

Comment: Aside from `glGenTextures`, those are all GL 1.0. Texture objects were not added until GL 1.1. The state associated with them existed though, so that's why `glTexParameteri` is GL 1.0. Also, you mean API; ABI has to do with lower-level things like how variables are passed to functions on the CPU.

Comment: Yes, 1.1 was a typo, but corrected. I took ABI from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873784/when-do-i-need-to-use-an-opengl-function-loader

Comment: I don't think that GL functions aren't even the root cause here. You most likely get `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error at the draw call, because your opengl code is just not compatible to OpenGL core profile, i.e. you have no VAO or no shader bound at the time of the draw call.

Comment: @derhass Indeed, I was missing core profile bit on context flags, and forward compatible bit on profile mask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For example I replaced glDrawArrays with glDrawArraysEXT which fixed an earlier bug, but maybe there are more functions like this which need a newer version?

That's not how extensions work. `glDrawArraysEXT` is not a core OpenGL function; it's an extension function. Which you cannot call unless the implementation specifies that it implements this extension.

GL 1.0 did not have array rendering; glBegin/End was all you had. There was an extension made, EXT_vertex_arrays, that added `glDrawArraysEXT` and `glDrawElementsEXT` (among other things). Those were eventually absorbed into GL 1.1, and therefore lost the EXT suffix.

To put it another way, `glDrawArraysEXT` was *replaced by* `glDrawArrays`, not the other way around. So if using the EXT version "fixed an earlier bug", it did not; it only *appeared* to do so. So you shouldn't be looking for extension functions to replace your core functions with.

---

For your specific question, there are many [OpenGL loaders](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) that will generate only the OpenGL functions used in a particular version of the API. "glLoadGen" (mine) can do it, but "glad" can also do it.

Comment: Adding to this, extensions suffixed with `ARB` are not implicitly "core" (designed to bring functions from later versions of the spec. to older drivers) either. The original ARB GLSL extensions, for example, are radically different in form than the finalized 2.0 specification. Prior to OpenGL 2.0, I stupidly assumed that `..._ARB` extensions and functions suffixed with `ARB` were the same thing as their suffix-less counterparts defined in the next specification version. Boy was I wrong ;) That was rectified by 3.0, with "core" extensions defining function and constant names free from suffixes.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: "*That was rectified by 3.0, with "core" extensions defining function and constant names free from suffixes.*" Not all ARB extensions do that post-3.0. They only do that when they are exposing functionality that was core at the same time the extension came out. ARB_draw_buffers_blend being one example: it was released in advance of GL 4.0 (when the functionality became core); as such, it uses suffixes. ARB_bindless_texture has them too, since it isn't core. ARB extensions are simply those that are cross-vendor which the ARB has "blessed" or controlled the development of.

Comment: That is what I was trying to say. Long ago, I had a flawed notion that `ARB` extensions brought future functionality backwards and could be assumed perfect fallbacks. As mentioned, extensions defined before a release append function/constant suffixes. Extensions defined simultaneously to backport something that is required by a release have no suffixes on their tokens--they match verbatim the newly defined interface. The point I was getting at is that a constant or function name with `ARB` at the end may or may not be equivalent to a core feature, you cannot infer anything from name.

Comment: This answer helped me understand opengl extensions better. Purely for your interest, I fixed the actual bug by adding context flag = core profile bit and profile mask = forward compatible bit to the wglCreateContextAttribsARB attribs. So the opengl calls themselves turned out not to be the problem in the end, but thanks anyway - you helped me narrow down what the problem wasn't!

Answer (score 2):

I have a proof of concept project on GitHub that may help you out.

Khronos provides an XML file in the OpenGL registry that describes every version of the API and every standard constant. They use this to build the API documentation, among other things. The XML file is searchable if you parse it, but I am aware of few tools that do this.

This [simple program](https://github.com/andon13/glvs) written in C++ in about an hour will tell you everything you want to know about an extension, constant or function. That includes which version it is core in, whether it's optional, if there are any aliases (extensions that provide the same functionality) and what version it was deprecated and/or removed in.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, but one thing I intentionally omitted to mention was I'm doing my opengl programming in C#, and have no idea how to compile a C++ program. If you provide a pre-complied version I'm happy to check it out! :)

Answer (score 2):

**In response to your follow-up comment (re: ABI), I believe I see what you were getting at and it is not what I initially answered.**

*Though unrelated, I think the code repository originally discussed has some relevance to the discussion and opted to keep it separate. This answer instead discusses the ABI as it relates to the three major platforms you are likely to encounter (Windows, GNU/Linux and Mac OS X), with special emphasis on Windows because it is the only platform that could realistically behave the way you are suggesting.*

Beginning with Windows 95 OSR2, `OpenGL32.dll` has provided an ABI compatible with OpenGL 1.1, it is functionally complete up to 1.1. That status never changed -- anything not defined in OpenGL 1.1 requires an Installable Client Driver (ICD) -- and the only change in 20 years has been the introduction of a 64-bit version of `OpenGL32.dll`.

GNU/Linux, as a platform, has NO guarantee of ANY OpenGL support whatsoever (thus no standard ABI), and Apple is/was the real odd-ball with an ever changing ABI in each OS release.

Apple's ABI is tricky because there are plenty of functions you can link to and call, but that will do nothing aside from raise `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` when called from an unsupported context ***(sound familiar?!)***. Apple's decision to raise this error is at least consistent though never adequately discussed or shared with any other platform you will encounter. Extensions are meaningless on OS X, but Apple did define a mechanism in AGL to query their respective function pointers (for parity with every other platform perhaps?).

On Windows, the ABI never grew or shrank. 20 years ago it supported `glDrawArraysEXT` and to this day the reference GDI implementation still does. You do not generally run any software on the GDI implementation; it is slow as dirt and has little to no interaction with modern hardware accelerated layers of the platform.

Even though the platform was originally designed with hybrid GDI/Hardware drivers (Mini-Client Drivers) in mind, this never materialized. Installable Client Drivers (ICDs) implement everything `OpenGL32.dll` does at minimum in contrast to MCDs, which implement only a subset of `OpenGL32.dll` and may fallback to the platform's GDI abomination for anything else.

Since Mini Client Drivers were never practical and only intended as a quick stopgap (think DOS era Quake minidrivers), any and all OpenGL drivers you encounter on Windows will either be full-blown ICDs or completely software-based. You always have `glDrawArraysEXT` at your disposal and it is always provided by the same driver as every other part of OpenGL.

That is all well and good, ***but*** means very little because the `glDrawArraysEXT` function originally discussed is not the same thing as `glDrawArrays`. One followed from the other, but it is a mistake to dismiss it *"a newer version"* just as you probably prefer not to be labeled a newer version of your parents...

In all but a few cases, when calling something with `XYZ` tacked onto the end of it you can assume to be discussing something related to but not the same as the suffix free version.

If behavior changed when switching from `glDrawArrays` to `glDrawArraysEXT` and you are dealing with Windows (and reasonably assume that MCDs do not exist), that is because the function is supposed to have different behavior (or you have a buggy driver) -- not because it was provided by something else.

*Windows was the only platform designed with a driver model that might arbitrarily split its GL implementation across multiple drivers and since that factoid applies nowhere but history books, this should cover all bases.*

Comment: **TL;DR:** If you can link to it, you can call it (unless it's Apple, then you must think different) ;)