# Why are there no buffers in <gl/GL.h>

Tags: c++, opengl

A tutorial that was following showed me the following code:

```cpp
...

void update() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    glVertex4f(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glVertex4f(1, 0, 0, 0);
    glVertex4f(0, 1, 0, 0);

    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

...
```

It worked just fine, but I know from OpenTK's tutorial that the Core profile is much better, since it's much more flexible and fast.

So I followed another tutorial, which used buffers. It showed something like the following code:

```cpp
float data[] = {
    0, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0
}
GLuint vao;

void update () {
    ...
}

void main() {
    // glut stuff

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
}
...
```

The problem is that `<gl/GL.h>` (for some reason) doesn't have any buffer-related function definitions. I really can't figure out why is that, so do I have to download another library I don't know about, or am I missing something?

I'm using Visual Studio and the default header file (if that matters at all).

Comment: On many systems, the default OpenGL headers only provide the OpenGL function for the older version ([When do I need to use an OpenGL function loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873784)). And you need to load and point to the functions. To avoid the need to do this manually there are loaders like [glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/) or [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: You have to use an OpenGL loader like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [GLAD](https://glad.dav1d.de/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to t.niese and Rabbid76 for solving my problem so quickly!

Here are their solutions:

---

### t.niese

On many systems, the default OpenGL headers only provide the OpenGL function for the older version ([When do I need to use an OpenGL function loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873784)). And you need to load and point to the functions. To avoid the need to do this manually there are loaders like [glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/) or [glew](http://glew.sourceforge.net/)

### Rabbid76

You have to use an OpenGL loader like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [GLAD](https://glad.dav1d.de/)